# Understanding C++ and Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm not that much experienced in C++ and still learning and I keep forgetting important details which makes life difficult for me in understanding others codes or example or using extra libraries. Also for my school task I'm having to learn to work with Qt. So, now I'm trying to understand an example where I faced the following line code.

A class `FileDialog` is declared in header file as below:

```
class FileDialog : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FileDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~FileDialog();

private slots:
    void changeDirectory();
    void fillList();

private:
    Ui::FileDialogClass* ui;
    QDir directory;

};
```

In the other source .cpp file, which is not a main file, the constructor of the class is filled like this:

```
    FileDialog::FileDialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::FileDialogClass), directory("/")
{
    ui->setupUi(this);dir
    setWindowTitle("Changing Directory");

    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(changeDirectory()));
    fillList();
}
```

Here, I'm not quite clear about the line

```
FileDialog::FileDialog(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::FileDialogClass), directory("/")
```

I presume `FileDialog::FileDialog(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)` written because `FileDialog` is a `QMainWindow` type class, right? But we why do we add `ui(new Ui::FileDialogClass), directory("/")`? Please also explain why is `directory()` passed with a string `"/"`, is it to give a hint how the program will understand which is a directory and which is a file?

I should also add how other two functions `changeDirectory` and `fillList` is filled.

```
void FileDialog::changeDirectory()
{
    QString path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Directory"), directory.path());
    if ( path.isNull() == false )
    {
        directory.setPath(path);
        fillList();
    }
}

void FileDialog::fillList()
{
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    ui->listWidget->addItems(directory.entryList());
}
```

If possible please explain how the function `tr()` is working in directly above stated code, I tried to read the documentation but I'm quite getting it :(.
Please don't be bothered if my questions are very silly? Thanks alot.

Comment: `ui` is probably populated by Qt Creator.

Comment: What does "private slots:" mean?  I've never encountered anything but a colon to the right of the access modifier.

Comment: @Eric: It's part of Qt. This will be modified by an Qt tool (moc) to valid C++ code I think.

Comment: @Skalli: e-gag, wow, I was thinking of looking at QT for my next endeavor but with that crazy crap going on, no way.  A pre-compiler for the C++ library is just bad engineering; really bad if it's required to use the QT framework.  Can QT be used without MOC pre-processing?

Comment: @Eric: As far as I know: No. You need the MOC, but I haven't tried working without it. Yet you won't notice this additional step during development. I don't think it's a criterion for not using Qt. Qt itself is a quite impresive library.

Comment: @Skalli: QT does seem impressive on all accounts but learning about your QT code depending some pre-processor just seems like one more area to debug (or at least question) when terse compiler messages are at the helm.....  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Eric: I've done some smaller projects with Qt and so far I've never had any trouble with the moc'ing. I also don't know how much they rely on it in Qt 5. The moc'ing was introduced to make the Signal/Slot concept easier and templates were having some issues while they were developing Qt 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, about the following part :

```
FileDialog::FileDialog(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::FileDialogClass), directory("/")
```

This is a constructor initialization list. In this list, you'll find :

- Call to the base class constructor : this is the `QMainWindow(parent)`.
- Initialization of member variables : each listed member variable, separated by commas, is initialized with the specified value (E.g.: the `ui` member is initialized with `new Ui::FileDialogClass`.

Then, about `directory`. It is a `QDir` variable, and is initialized with the value `"/"` which corresponds to the root directory on UNIX systems.

Finally, [as explained in the Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#tr), `tr()` is a function used for internationalization (returning the desired translation, depending on the locale/language set for the application).

Answer (score -4):

Here is the answers to your [first](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr388.htm) [second](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#QDir-2) and [third](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/i18n-source-translation.html) questions. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please answer the question here itself, rather than linking to external sites. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Are you seriously suggesting that Amartel should have *copied and pasted* the Qt docs into his answer!?

Comment: @cmannett85 Not at all.. There is no need to copy the entire QT doc to answer the question.. But answer in the current format is of zero help if the links went down. Also even if we left the answer as it as, there is an automatic script that will convert this answer as a comment.

Comment: The question clearly states "understanding C++ and Qt", this means there is a high chance that the OP is a beginner, in which case the documentation is cryptic at best.

Comment: Link-only answers should at least describe the links shortly, so much that it's clear why the links are in the answer. Also if links break, answer should have enough info to google for new location or similar pages.